# SWIFT Array of HealthKt Samples divided up into Array groups by date then shown on UITableView

Tags: arrays, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Could I please have some help making a table with section headers that are the days of the week, Starting with the current day, eg. If today is Saturday then Saturday is the first section head, and then for the past 7 days.  The data comes from an array called workouts that is made up of HealthKit Samples. I can find the date by printing workout.startDate or workout.endDate

This is what workouts looks like with 3 sample workouts in the array that I got by running a HealthKit query. You can see that 2020-05-22 is repeated twice because there was two workouts on that day.

> var workouts: [HKSample]?
>
> print(workouts) = [0 0A48A590-67BD-4121-BE59-3DA80CC88880 "App_Name"
>   (1), "iPhone12,3" (13.5) (2020-05-24 14:36:18 +1000 - 2020-05-24
>   14:37:12 +1000), 0 F744E642-C3D0-4DB4-A93A-E9AF89B6197A "App_Name" (1),
>   "iPhone12,3" (13.5) (2020-05-22 17:13:31 +1000 - 2020-05-22 17:18:16
>   +1000), 0 674CDF99-ED50-4EB6-B733-1786184AD92F "App_Name" (1), "iPhone12,3" (13.5) (2020-05-22 17:03:19 +1000 - 2020-05-22 17:03:51
>   +1000)]

I would like to seperate those into an array that is like [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]] with seperate days so I can count them for the rows in the sections and count the section heads. Also if the array for that day isEmpty I would like to to NOT show it on the table.

> var workoutsByDate: [[HKSample]]?
>
> workoutsByDate = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

Then id like to get the section head for the UITableview by just getting the day of the week -

```
let workoutDayFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    return formatter
}()

for workout in workouts! {
    let workoutDay = workoutDayFormatter.string(from: workout.startDate)
    print (workoutDay)
}

Prints 
Sunday
Friday
Friday
```

Then make a table with day sections and the corresponding workout underneath. It would take me weeks to figure this out. At the moment the table just shows all that data with no sections.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numOfSections = Int(workouts?.count ?? 0)
    return numOfSections
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! woroutTableViewCell
    let workout = workouts[indexPath.row]
    let workoutStartDate = dateFormatter.string(from: workout.startDate)
    let rawStartDate = workout.startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let rawEndDate = workout.endDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let workoutStartTime = dateFormatter2.string(from: workout.startDate)
    let cellTitleString = "\(workoutStartDate) at \(workoutStartTime)"
    cell.dateLabel?.text = "\(cellTitleString)"
    let sessionDurationTotalTime = TimeInterval(rawEndDate - rawStartDate)
    var sessionDurationTimeInSeconds = TimeInterval(rawEndDate - rawStartDate)
    let hours = Int(sessionDurationTimeInSeconds / 3600.0)
    sessionDurationTimeInSeconds -= (TimeInterval(hours) * 3600)
    let minutes = Int(sessionDurationTimeInSeconds / 60.0)
    sessionDurationTimeInSeconds -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
    let seconds = Int(sessionDurationTimeInSeconds)
    sessionDurationTimeInSeconds -= TimeInterval(seconds)
    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let sessionDurationTimeString = "\(hours)hr \(strMinutes)min \(strSeconds)sec"
    let cellTimeString = "\(sessionDurationTimeString)"
    cell.durationLabel?.text = "\(cellTimeString)"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few weeks and I came up with the solution. I'll post it here for future reference or if it helps someone else. Feel free to provide your own answer or improve mine.

I created sections from the day of the week in the HKSample.startDate

[image]

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [HKSample]!
}
var objectArray = [Objects]()
```

...

```
self.objectArray = [Objects]()
var userObjects = [HKSample] ()
var prevHeader = ""
let formatter = DateFormatter()
for i in 0...samples!.count-1 {
    let sample = samples![i].startDate
    formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("eeee")
    let dayOfWeek = formatter.string(from: sample)
    
     if prevHeader == "" {
         userObjects.append(samples![i])
     }
     else if prevHeader == dayOfWeek {
         userObjects.append(samples![i])
     }
     else {
         self.objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: prevHeader, sectionObjects: userObjects))
         userObjects = [HKSample] ()
         userObjects.append(samples![i])
     }
     prevHeader = dayOfWeek
 }
    self.objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: prevHeader, sectionObjects: userObjects))
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! sampleTableViewCell
    let sample =  objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateLabel?.text = ... decorate cell ...
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return objectArray.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return objectArray[section].sectionName.uppercased()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}
```